# Unable to Run my First MEAN Application on Heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

**server.js file:**

```
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var express = require('express');
var app = require('./app');
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
var http = require('http');
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

**db.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.connnect = function(){
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);
  console.log("Connected Successfully--!");
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js",
  "readme": "README.md",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.14.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.4",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "engines" :{
    "node": "4.4.5",
    "npm": "3.10.5"
  }
}
```

**My Procfile File**

```
web: node server.js
```

I included `README.md` file, all packages everything

But whenever I push the project into github after build it is showing:

```
2016-07-17T09:43:46.021568+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs myapp
2016-07-17T09:43:46.021700+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls myapp
2016-07-17T09:43:46.021811+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-07-17T09:43:46.026030+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-07-17T09:43:46.026324+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-07-17T09:43:46.912101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-07-17T09:43:46.926177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

When I executed the command `npm bugs myapp` when I was directed to new page in browser showing: [image: Error description Page]

But whenever i am trying to run my app showing errors like

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-harbor-57127.herokuapp.com request_id=13794f33-cebe-46bc-8222-f908466bc7e2 fwd="103.15.60.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
2016-07-17T10:21:13.984164+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-harbor-57127.herokuapp.com request_id=ae23dbea-9894-4bdd-ab9d-3bcd5d202fb5 fwd="103.15.60.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I don't know what to do; the app is working perfectly on my local system but I don't know why this is causing errors on Heroku.

https://aqueous-harbor-57127.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should show a bit more log above :

```
npm ERR!     npm bugs myapp
```

this line :

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-harbor-57127.herokuapp.com request_id=13794f33-cebe-46bc-8222-f908466bc7e2 fwd="103.15.60.210" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Is basically saying that your app crashed and return 503
There is not much that can fail in your example, so I will try a guess :

```
process.env.MONGOLAB_URI
```

Did you correctly set env for your heroku app ?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-config-vars